# How can CSS seemingly make static HTML pages dynamic?

Tags: html, css

Occasionally, css adds dynamic to pure html pages. For example, changing the background colour on hover. I want to understand, how does the css work?

CSS:

```
 div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
  }
  div:hover {
    background: red;
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <html>
  <body>
     <div></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

[plnkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/75vfFYGZoCkvqUBB8bep)

When mouse enters "div" does browser just override background to black (i.e browser leaves height: 100px, width: 100px and position: absolute) or recalculates it ?

In usual case, when some event happens and changes css of an element, does it just override properties which are present in css style ? In other words, after some several events, does style of an element might end up arbitrary?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [**off-topic for Stack Overflow**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274647/2802040)

Comment: Also theres _tons_ (literally, if you would print it it would probably destroy the amazon rain forest for paper) of documentation and tutorials on this. Use Google, your best friend.

Comment: @Paulie_D Huh? How is this question asking that? Did you perhaps mean too broad instead? Or maybe "unclear what you're asking"?

Comment: Check the link for "off-topic" I gave....this has come up before.

Answer (score 2):

> In usual case, when some event happens and changes css of an element, does it just override properties which are present in css style ?

The element begins to match a new selector. A new rule-set is applied to the element. The properties of the element are recalculated according to the standard rules for the cascade.

> In other words, after some several events, does style of an element might end up arbitrary?

No. The rules for the cascade (which defines which order rules are applied in) are (very) clearly defined in the specification. There is nothing arbitrary about them.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: When you hover over an element, the element goes into the `:hover` state. It now matches two selectors in the CSS file: `div` and `div:hover`. All the properties of both rule sets are applied to the element. Where there are conflicts, e.g. `background` defined on both, the more *specific* selector wins (*read the spec, the rules aren't easily summarised).

When you leave the element, it goes out of its `:hover` state. The `div:hover` selector does not apply anymore, only one rule set applies now. All the element's style properties are recalculated from scratch, resulting in the `background` turning `black` again (because it's the only rule that applies).

Everything is in a very defined state at all times, the changes are not incremental and will never result in weird states because something didn't get unset or such.